# Cannot register activity to open email attachments on Android

Tags: android

I've been working on an update for [Shopping Assistant](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.blogspot.hypersynapse.sa&feature=search_result), a shopping list management application and what I am trying to do now is create a functionality that will email shopping lists which are nothing but json encoded text files that contain a shopping list created with the application to a different user that has the application installed. When the email is received, and one tries to preview/open the attachment, the Shopping Assistant app should be presented as an option to open the attachment. However, no matter what intent filers I have tried, this doesn't work. I can't get my app to be called when the attachment is previewed.
  It is true that I created a custom mime type called application/sal (sal is the extension I give to the file attachment) and added an intent filter to the manifest file that looks something like this:

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/sal" />
        </intent-filter>
```

but with no success. I've also tried to use text/xml as a mime type in the email and also in the filter (file content remaining the same), and with that I got a dialog for choosing between file viewer and another app, but still Shopping Assistant didn't show in the list.

I've been reading examples and questions on this subject from StackOverflow and other forums, and none of the examples helped, so any suggestions for my particular conundrum would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mihai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is true that I created a custom mime type called application/sal

No email client knows about this, and hence it will not be used by the sender. This means it will not be received on your device.

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW" />`

Remove `ACTION_` from your value.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Apparently the problem was the ACTION_VIEW action for the intent, that needed to be only VIEW and the custom mime type works just fine, I think email clients are able to handle all application types application/* so there is room for adding a custom extension there. Man, I've been desperate to find a solution for this, and it turned out to be such a trivial thing that I missed out, thanks again for the observation, it was invaluable.